# Checking the percentage format of a cell

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

Background:

- Someone gives me data that is meant to be formatted in a certain way.
- I have a VBA program that performs different checks based on certain rules.
- One of these rules is that all percentage values should be in decimal format.

I need to be able to pick up that they have the put the values in the format 12.34% instead of 0.1234.

Problem:

I can't find a way to pick up the percentage formatting as Excel/VBA auto-converts the format to decimal.

I've tried (along with some other attempts):

```
If CStr(Cells(j, i).Value) Like "*%*" Then

     ' add incorrectly formatted data location to report

End If

'I've also tried

If Cells(j, i).NumberFormat = "##.##%" Then
```

I initially tried without the string conversion function (Cstr()) but that yielded the same result.

I've seen the format() function exists, but that converts to different formats rather than performing a check.

Any idea on how to check the actual value of the cell (without changing the data) without excel performing an auto-conversion?

I'd like to avoid regex if possible as it is slow and the datasets are large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.Text` rather than `.Value`:

```
If CStr(Cells(j, i).Text) Like "*%*" Then
```

*(you don't even need `CStr`)*

**EDIT#1:**

There are some limitations/dangers associated with using `.Text`.  You only get a "WYSIWYG" snap-shot of the cell's appearance:

- you can't tell if the cell contains a numeric value or a text value
- if the column is too narrow, you might only get "###" rather than the underlying value

Comment: Two issues with that: **a)** the `Text`-Property shows *exactly* what's displayed. If a cell shows `###` because the width is to small to display the value,   `Text` will return `###`. If a cell is hidden, `Text` returns an empty string. **b)** If user entered a *string* `12.34%` (or `XYZ%`), the `If` would return `True`

Comment: @FunThomas  You are 100% correct !  I will update my answer to mention your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

I have coded the following that should work any time:

Get the format, and convert it as a string:

```
    sFormat = CStr(Sheet1.Range("b2").NumberFormat)
```

*sFormat* will now be a string "0%"

Then, check the last character of the format

```
    If Right(sFormat, 1) = "%" Then
```